# Hibernate & JPA jars required for Spring 3.1.0 version

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-3, spring-orm

I have been migrating my application from spring version 4.0 to spring 3.1.0. 
I have wasted the entire day & could not find the exact jar dependencies & their versions. It would be really helpful if someone here can suggest on about the version of Hibernate & JPA jars I should be using for Spring version 3.1.0 (or any would be appreciated).

Thanks in advance.

Things I have tried for migration:

1. Changed version of all jars for spring.
2. Now while trying to change the version of jars for jpa :

   a) changed spring-data-jpa-1.6.0.RELEASE to spring-data-jpa-1.2.0.RELEASE

   b) changed spring-data-commons-1.9.2.RELEASE to spring-data-commons-1.4.0.RELEASE.

And now the error I am getting :

`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Invalid NamespaceHandler class [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryNameSpaceHandler] for namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa]: problem with handler class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`

**Jar Snapshot**
  [image]

**applicationContext.xml**(**Spring configuration xml**)

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
xmlns:repository="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">`
```

Comment: Why would you downgrade your application?

Comment: Because, in our organisation we have some predefined plugins (for example: logonmanager) which uses spring version 3.1.0. Previously we were using 4.0 for our other client.

Comment: Which hibernate versions have you tried?

Comment: 4.2.3.Final is the current version of hibernate for spring 4.0 we are using currently.

Comment: And what isn't working? What have you tried? Stack traces, config... Please improve your question.

Comment: Done, please look at my edited question.

Comment: To me it looks like you have the wrong `spring-orm` dependency. Incompatible with 3.1.0... I would however urge you to upgrade as the 3.x branch isn't supported anymore.

Comment: Also manually trying to match compatible jar versions is something you shouldn't be doing in the first place. You really should be using something like maven or gradle to handle that for you.

Answer (score 0):

This should fit to spring 3.1.0

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
   <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the preaching, but you really should invest time in upgrading those outdated plugins (or scrapping) them instead of downgrading to an ancient version of Spring (or any relevant library). There have been countless improvements added including security relevant patches.

To answer the actual question: Use Maven.

Either base your application directly on Maven or use the information from Maven poms.

The latest 3.1.x version for `spring-orm` is 3.1.4. Here is the pom for that artefact: http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-orm/3.1.4.RELEASE/spring-orm-3.1.4.RELEASE.pom

For hibernate it specifies

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
   <version>3.6.0.Final</version>
   <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

If you are using Maven or similar, this should be sufficient to pull in a compatible version of Hibernate with all necessary dependencies including the JPA API. If you don't use Maven, set up a tiny maven project with that dependency. Use the dependency plugin to list all dependencies including transient ones with their version:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```